# javascript 3 state checkbox

Tags: javascript, html

I have a very long list of items each with a checkbox that has 3 states (Yes=ticked, No=X'd, Not Applicable=unticked). Using a checkbox I was able to toggle with 3 states using .indeterminate element, as follows:

```js
function chkbx(cb) {
    if (cb.readOnly) cb.checked = cb.readOnly = false;
    else if (!cb.checked) cb.readOnly = cb.indeterminate = true;
    else if (cb.checked) cb.readOnly = cb.indeterminate = false;
}

function showtext() {
if (cert27.checked) {document.getElementById('BoxB27').style.display = "block";} else {document.getElementById('BoxB27').style.display = "none";}

if (!cert27.checked) {document.getElementById('BoxA27').style.display = "block";} else {document.getElementById('BoxA27').style.display = "none";}

if (cert27.indeterminate) {document.getElementById('BoxC27').style.display = "block";} else {document.getElementById('BoxC27').style.display = "none";}     
if (cert28.checked) {document.getElementById('BoxB28').style.display = "block";} else {document.getElementById('BoxB28').style.display = "none";}

if (!cert28.checked) {document.getElementById('BoxA28').style.display = "block";} else {document.getElementById('BoxA28').style.display = "none";}

if (cert28.indeterminate) {document.getElementById('BoxC28').style.display = "block";} else {document.getElementById('BoxC28').style.display = "none";}         

}
```

```html
<body>
<table>
<tr>
<td><input type="checkbox" id="cert27" value="25" onclick="showtext();chkbx(this);" /></td>
<td>Banannas</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><input type="checkbox" id="cert28" value="15" onclick="showtext();chkbx(this);" /></td>
<td>Sugar</td>
</tr>
</table>

<span id="BoxA27" style="display:none">Bananas excluded.</span>
<span id="BoxB27" style="display:none">Bananas included.</span>
<span id="BoxC27" style="display:none">Bananas are N/A.</span>
<span id="BoxA28" style="display:none">Sugar excluded.</span>
<span id="BoxB28" style="display:none">Sugar included.</span>
<span id="BoxC28" style="display:none">Sugar is N/A.</span>

</body>
```

However, when changing the state of a checkbox, it not only messes up the displayed text, but also for changes the other boxes texts and does not correctly show the checkbox status.

How do I get the correct status of each checkbox, and display the correct text?

Answer (score 1):

When you click on a `checkbox` you first need to call `chkbx()` to update its state and then call `showtext()`.

Then, to handle the message displayed for each of the state, you should use `if...else if...else` because `!checkbox.checked` and `checkbox.indeterminate` can both be `true` at the same time :

```js
function chkbx(cb) {
    if (cb.readOnly) cb.checked = cb.readOnly = false;
    else if (!cb.checked) cb.readOnly = cb.indeterminate = true;
    else if (cb.checked) cb.readOnly = cb.indeterminate = false;
}

function showtext() {

  if(cert27.checked){
    document.getElementById('BoxB27').style.display = "block";
    document.getElementById('BoxA27').style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById('BoxC27').style.display = "none";
  } else if (cert27.indeterminate) {
    document.getElementById('BoxC27').style.display = "block";
    document.getElementById('BoxA27').style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById('BoxB27').style.display = "none";
  } else {
    document.getElementById('BoxA27').style.display = "block";
    document.getElementById('BoxB27').style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById('BoxC27').style.display = "none";
  }
  
  if(cert28.checked){
    document.getElementById('BoxB28').style.display = "block";
    document.getElementById('BoxA28').style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById('BoxC28').style.display = "none";
  } else if (cert28.indeterminate) {
    document.getElementById('BoxC28').style.display = "block";
    document.getElementById('BoxA28').style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById('BoxB28').style.display = "none";
  } else {
    document.getElementById('BoxA28').style.display = "block";
    document.getElementById('BoxB28').style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById('BoxC28').style.display = "none";
  }

}
```

```html
<body>
<table>
<tr>
<td><input type="checkbox" id="cert27" value="25" onclick="chkbx(this);showtext();" /></td>
<td>Banannas</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><input type="checkbox" id="cert28" value="15" onclick="chkbx(this);showtext();" /></td>
<td>Sugar</td>
</tr>
</table>

<span id="BoxA27" style="display:none">Bananas excluded.</span>
<span id="BoxB27" style="display:none">Bananas included.</span>
<span id="BoxC27" style="display:none">Bananas are N/A.</span>
<span id="BoxA28" style="display:none">Sugar excluded.</span>
<span id="BoxB28" style="display:none">Sugar included.</span>
<span id="BoxC28" style="display:none">Sugar is N/A.</span>

</body>
```